# Empty returned value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, switch-statement

I want to make a function that will get the transaction code but the returned value is empty.

I am calling this function from my model.

```
public function getTransactionCode($type){

    switch($type)
    {
        case '52';
        $count = $this->where('type_id',$type)
                    ->count('id');
        $next = (intval($count) ?: 0) + 1;
        $code = "LAP-00{$next}";
        return $code;

        case '53';
        $count = $this->where('type_id',$type)
                    ->count('id');
        $next = (intval($count) ?: 0) + 1;
        $code = "PC-00{$next}";
        return $code;

        case '54';
        $count = $this->where('type_id',$type)
                    ->count('id');
        $next = (intval($count) ?: 0) + 1;
        $code = "TAB-00{$next}";
        return $code;

        case '55';
        $count = $this->where('type_id',$type)
                    ->count('id');
        $next = (intval($count) ?: 0) + 1;
        $code = "OOE-00{$next}";
        return $code;

    }
  
}
```

And I want to pull any value from my model with this function on my controller.

```
 $code = $this->equipment->getTransactionCode($type = '');
```

But it keeps returning empty value.

Answer (score 1):

As @shaedrich suggested, `switch` does not return anything. However, you can assign value to a variable then return after `switch` statement.

Also There should be **Colon(:)** after `case` not **Semi-colon (;)**

```
public function getTransactionCode($type){
    $code = 'ANY DEFAULT VALUE'; // Needs to set any desired value here

    switch($type)
    {
        case '52':
        $count = $this->where('type_id',$type)
                    ->count('id');
        $next = (intval($count) ?: 0) + 1;
        $code = "LAP-00{$next}";
        break;

        case '53':
        $count = $this->where('type_id',$type)
                    ->count('id');
        $next = (intval($count) ?: 0) + 1;
        $code = "PC-00{$next}";
        break;

        case '54':
        $count = $this->where('type_id',$type)
                    ->count('id');
        $next = (intval($count) ?: 0) + 1;
        $code = "TAB-00{$next}";
        break;

        case '55':
        $count = $this->where('type_id',$type)
                    ->count('id');
        $next = (intval($count) ?: 0) + 1;
        $code = "OOE-00{$next}";
        break;
    }
    
    return $code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is not really designed to `return`.

```
public function getTransactionCode($type){
    $count = $this->where('type_id',$type)
                  ->count('id');
    $next = (intval($count) ?: 0) + 1;

    if ($type === '52') {
        return "LAP-00{$next}";
    } else if ($type === '53') {
        return "PC-00{$next}";
    } else if ($type === '54') {
        return "TAB-00{$next}";
    } else if ($type === '55') {
        return "OOE-00{$next}";
    }
  
}
```